# Can't start elasticsearch's service

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am not able to start elasticsearch's service. I configured everything in elasticsearch. But when I run its service, I am getting the following error.

```
 $Stopping elasticsearch: /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: 129: /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: killproc: not found

 $Starting elasticsearch: /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: 119: /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: daemon: not found
```

I don't know what mistake I did. Can anyone give me any suggestions to clear this issue and start service.

Comment: what command did you run? did you set the path for the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: I run the command sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart

Comment: usually, from the command line (using windows)  i run the elasticsearch service from its bin folder for Ex. c:/elasticsearch1.1.1/bin  im assuming you are using ubuntu?

Comment: have you tried the following sequence (3 different commands)?

sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload

sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service

Comment: I am using ubuntu. So /bin/systemctl command not found

Answer (score 1):

from Elastic Searches docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html

> RPM based distributionsedit Using chkconfigedit
>
> Some RPM based distributions are using chkconfig to enable and disable
>   services. The init script is located at /etc/init.d/elasticsearch,
>   where as the configuration file is placed at
>   /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch. Like the debian package the RPM package
>   is not started by default after installation, you have to do this
>   manually by entering the following commands

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add elasticsearch 
startsudo service elasticsearch
```

sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service

> Distributions like Debian Jessie, Ubuntu 14, and many of the SUSE
>   derivatives do not use the chkconfig tool to register services, but
>   rather systemd and its command /bin/systemctl to start and stop
>   services (at least in newer versions, otherwise use the chkconfig
>   commands above)

```
sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180342/running-init-d-script-produces-start-stop-daemon-not-found

> add PATH to your script PRIOR TO /bin or /sbin. Since the init script
>   might not share the PATH environment variable with the rest of the
>   system you might need to set it directly in your script and make sure
>   /bin or /sbin is in there:

Ex:

```
PATH=/bin/systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: i did the same thing as you said. am getting the same error $Starting elasticsearch: /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: 119: /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: daemon: not found

Comment: i re-edited my post, please check last part, please follow the link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180342/running-init-d-script-produces-start-stop-daemon-not-found as mentioned above, mabe it can provide usefull